# Subscribe users to a list using MailChimp API v3 and CURL

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am wondering if anyone has worked with MailChimp API to subscribe users to the list.

I am wondering how it is done, from the documentation I am trying to accomplish.

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists' \
--user 'anystring:apikey' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"name":"Freddie'\''s Favorite Hats","contact":{"company":"MailChimp","address1":"675 Ponce De Leon Ave NE","address2":"Suite 5000","city":"Atlanta","state":"GA","zip":"30308","country":"US","phone":""},"permission_reminder":"You'\''re receiving this email because you signed up for updates about Freddie'\''s newest hats.","campaign_defaults":{"from_name":"Freddie","from_email":"freddie@freddiehats.com","subject":"","language":"en"},"email_type_option":true}' \
--include
```

My attempt was this:

```
$apiKey ='mykey';
$listID = 'id';
$email = 'my@email.com';
$data = array(
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status' => 'subscribed'
);

$body = json_encode($data);

$opts = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'apikey ' . $apiKey
    ),
    'body' => $body
);

$apiKeyParts = explode('-', $apiKey);
$shard = $apiKeyParts[1];

$url = '//' . $shard . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/';

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, $opts );

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $result = $response->get_error_message();
} else {
    // DEBUG
    $result = print_r($response, true);
}

return $result;
```

However it never worked, I also found another post stating ("i got this to work") but for me it was returning false.

Comment: What error message is being returned? MailChimp won't return "false" they'll return an error message that will tell you what is wrong with your request. Check out [the documentation on errors](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#errors).

Comment: But also: it looks like you're missing the 'https' in your `url`.

Comment: Since `wp_remote_post()`, is a WordPress function, it would be good to mention that someplace.  Edited tags.  Thanks.